JWT token is invalid
I recently changed my number. Stupidly I forgot to update my Authy. Eventually I was able to change my number on Authy to my new one, but whenever I try to sign in with my new number it’s keeps giving me the error: JWT Token is invalid.
Not sure what to do here but any help would be much appreciated.
Cheers
I’ve tried resetting/deleting and reinstalling the app. Nothing has changed. I can’t find anyone to contact regarding this

Had the same problem, I just clean the cache, lear the data and force stop the app and It worked for mee..

I changed my phone , mantaining the phone number. I tried to install authy on the new phone but i receive the error jwt error or http443 forbidden.
